# Use of uppercase in navigation.

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, interface, human-interface-guideline

Is it preferable to use uppercase in navigation on an online application for bankers and traders?

Comment: This question is about implementation, but this Stack Exchange is about User Experience, so your question is likely to be put on hold. Perhaps consider rewriting your question to be around designing the user experience for Bankers and Traders?

Comment: Your question could be meaningful here, if it has comparison/baffling issues between two GUI's been researched by you.

Comment: @Priyanka Goyal You can get answer by updating your question and elaborating more on the puzzle you trying to solve or trying to understand, but for that you need to put on some of your research work.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is a good Idea.

Comment: I can't decide if this in an implementation question or not. But, either way, questions that contain the phrase "What to keep in mind when designing for..." are too open for this forum. There are just too many variable to take into account and the number of possible answers is just endless. If you had a specific UX problem then we could help you solve it but you're basically asking us to do all your user research for you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some internal requirement to use one system or another for bankers and traders, the fact that they are bankers and traders shouldn't be a consideration.  They are people, and so the issue is more what's best for people.

**For navigation, ease of scanning and recognition should be your focus**, more so than in most other forms of text.  So, you should be going with the options that are faster to recognise.  In terms of uppercase vs. lowercase (assuming you're referring to a Latin script), mixed case is typically faster to scan.  Namely, having the first letter as uppercase, and the following letters in that word as lowercase.  If navigation has more than one word, you can choose to do the same with every successive word, with the exceptions of acronyms, where you should keep all the letters uppercase.

Some arbitrary examples are: `Home`, `Cash Flow`, `ROI`, `New CPM`